# Windows was unable to complete the format error?

Tags: windows-10, cd-r, cd-rw

This happens on all my devices running windows 10. I am trying to format a CD-RW (Ive also tried DVD-R) using windows' built in format function. I need to "Format it like a USB Drive". Whenever I try to it goes for like 5 minutes then says "Windows was unable to complete the format". IVe also tried using the right click format method, and I've tried going through disk manager. Nothing seems to work. Ive triedverbatium, memorax, and a couple of other disk companies. It seems like an undocumented problem but nobody even seems to have heard of windows' formating option. Thanks for any help. Ive included an image of the popup.

[image: error Popup Image.]

I also want to mention that it says "Quick Format was not an option!" when I try quick Format. IDK what that means... Lol

Comment: You can't "Format it like a USB Drive", you need to format it "Like a CD" i.e. use UDF.

Comment: What do you mean? This is what pops up when i put the disk in. Here's a photo of what it prompts: [link](https://s19.postimg.org/uqjnnz7ar/format.png) . If I was formated it like a disk would I still easily be able to move files around on/off the disk like a USB drive?

Comment: Been far too long since I messed with optical drives, barely remember - see this - https://www.wikihow.com/Format-a-CD

Comment: I know how to format a drive @Tetsujin its just not working

Answer (score 1):

Yes, we cannot use Quick Format for DVD.

To format DVD drive, we need to use these method:

Method 1: Windows 10 disk management tool

1. Insert the blank or erased CD or DVD into your CD or DVD hard drive.
2. Type Control Panel in the search box and click Control Panel.
3. Go to Administrative Tools > Computer Management > Disk Management.
4. Right-click on the drive or partition to format and click on "Format".
5. Select the file system and set the cluster size.
6. Click "OK" to format the CD-RW or DVD-RW.

Method 2: Use Erase the DVD:

1. Insert the rewritable disc, such as a CD-RW, DVD-RW, DVD+RW, or DVD-RAM disc, into your computer's CD, DVD, or Blu-ray Disc burner.
2. Open Computer by clicking the Start button, and then clicking Computer.
3. In Windows Explorer, click the CD, DVD, or Blu-ray Disc burner icon.
4. On the toolbar, click **"Erase this disc"**, and then follow the steps in the wizard to successfully erase, clear or wipe CD or DVD.

Comment: I already said that I was unable to format the disk using Disk management. I was able to Erase the disk but I was not then able to access anything on it.

Comment: I realize now that I was unable to Erase the disk as well. [Photo](https://s19.postimg.org/3wo5g9rtf/format.png)

Comment: Thanks for this post.  I tried your answer, and realized going to Computer Management will require an administrator approval (which I need to go through IT for)  Sigh.  But I know what's wrong now:  I don't have permissions to write to a DVD drive.